# trouble knitting to pdf using Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)
```

```
mpg.hp <- mtcars %>%
  select(mpg, hp) %>%
  gt() %>%
  cols_label(mpg = "Miles per Gallon", hp = "Horsepower") %>%
    tab_header(title = "Car Info") %>%
  cols_align(align = c("auto")) %>%
  fmt_number(columns = 1, decimals = 2) %>%
  fmt_number(columns = 2, decimals = 1)

mpg.hp
```

Just trying to do something basic like make a dataframe into a table and knit a PDF with that table in it via RMarkdown. It will knit as an HTML but it won't knit as a PDF unless I remove the mpg.hp call. And when I try to knit to PDF I get:

*! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.
Error: LaTeX failed to compile stackoverflow1.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See stackoverflow1.log for more info.
Execution halted*

I've visited the website in the Error message and followed the instructions. I've also tried using inline code to call the table, all with no success. Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error since I don't have your data. Are you able to reproduce this error using one of the datasets built into `R`?

Comment: @max I've edited the original post to provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, there is a bug with gt which won't allow you to knit to pdf when calling tab_header() with a title but without a subtitle. I inserted a blank subtitle and that seemed to do the trick.

Comment: The answer here suggests that just adding `subtitle` might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/65113829/3968093